# Do bump outs on colonial homes typically have gutters?

Tags: gutters

I am going through a home inspection of a 100 year old home that was built in 1915. It is common to have a bump-out of 1-3 feet off the home. Do these bump out's generally have gutters or not? If so, please provide proof or reasoning behind either answer.

Comment: You typically have gutters where you need them. A 20 square foot bump-out roof may not need them. Depends on other factors (what's underneath, the climate, etc)

Comment: No gutters at all, anywhere on the house - perfectly normal, and no gutters to clog/clean. Gutters everywhere, even where no water would logically get into them (across gable ends, for instance) - also normal. Anywhere in between, yup, normal. How this affects or does not affect your life depends on other drainage and landscaping details (ie, grading around the house.)